# Disable shift key on startup in ms-access (Doesn't want to work)

Tags: vba, microsoft-access, microsoft-access-2010

I'm an advanced Access VBA programmer, and even though I have programmitcally set the 'Use Access Special Keys' to FALSE (using VBA), or set that option through the Access Options screen, I can still open the database using the shift key and still get to the database window without the autoexec macro running. My understanding is, if I **disable** the special keys option, and I try to open my database while holding the shift key, it should not allow me to bypass my Autoexec macro or bypass the 'Display Form' They should launch even while holding down the Shift Key.  Am i missing something?

I used: CurrentDb.Properties!AllowSpecialKeys = False

Using Access 2010. File is Access 2010 format  accdb.